# How to restrict users to read/write the data based on phone number in Firebase rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Currently, I have implemented a project folder structure similar to the below

[Project folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXkbO.png)

I have added the Phone authentication in my code.

Now with the help of Firebase rules, I would like to restrict my users to access the child (Phone number 1) based on authenticated phone number.

For instance, if I log-in with phone number "9999999999" then I would like to restrict the user to access only the child of "9999999999" in Firebase rules.

Could you suggest me here to improve the security here.

Comment: Please do not include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Additionally using phone numbers as keys may cause some pain down the road. You will probably be better off disassociating your keys from the data. That way, if a phone number changes (which they do) you won't have delete and re-create all the nodes that reference that one.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the phone number from the [users auth object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#phoneNumber) so using this you can do the limiting in security rules. Below are examples in Firestore, RTDB and Storage

Firestore

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{phoneNumber} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.phone_number == phoneNumber;
    }
}
```

Realtime Database

```
{
    "rules" : {
        "users" : {
            "$phoneNumber" : {
                ".read" : "request.auth.token.phone_number == $phoneNumber",
                ".write" : "request.auth.token.phone_number == $phoneNumber"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Storage

```
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /users/{phoneNumber} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth.token.phone_number == phoneNumber;
        }
    }
}
```